# How to achieve a groupbox type of control with following look and feel

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Hi i want to achieve some thing like a groupbox with controls insideit and there will be a rectangle border around that with a caption on top left where border is hidden for that area.

So how i can achieve some thing like this.

I tried to upload an image but could not.

Please let me know if htere is some way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following implementation. It does exactly what you are looking for:
http://programmerpayback.com/2008/11/26/silverlight-groupbox-control/

Here is another implementation (in case the first one doesn't work for you):
http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/groupbox/

HTH

Comment: been using the first one for a while now... works beautifully

Comment: About what source are you talking, the first link isn't a problem, if you need the source I can mirror it for you.